# Routes issue in laravel 4

Tags: php, routes, laravel, laravel-4

I am new to laravel and learning it now. I am giving following Route in `routes.php` file

```
Route::resource('contacts', 'ContactsController');
```

But when I load my page in browser, it gives me following error

```
Unhandled Exception

Message:

Call to undefined method Laravel\Routing\Route::resource()
Location:

/Users/zafarsaleem/Sites/learning-laravel/application/routes.php on line 35
```

My complete routes.php file is below

```
Route::resource('contacts', 'ContactsController');

Route::get('/', function()   //<------- This is line 35
{
    return View::make('home.index');
});
```

How can I remove this error?

**Edit**

ContactsController code is below and I want index() function to be used

```
class ContactsController extends BaseController {

/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function index()
{
    Contact::all();
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function create()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function store()
{
    $input = Input::json();

    Contact::create(array(
        'first_name' => $input->first_name
        'last_name' => $input->last_name
        'email_address' => $input->email_address
        'description' => $input->description
    ));
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    return Contact::find($id);
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function update($id)
{
    $contact = Contact::find($id);
    $input = Input::json();

    $contact->first_name = $input->first_name;
    $contact->last_name = $input->last_name;
    $contact->email_address = $input->email_ddress;
    $contact->description = $input->description;

    $contact->save();
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    return Contact::find($id)->delete();
}

}
```

**Edit 2**

I tried both following routes but ended up same below error

```
Route::resource('contacts', 'ContactsController', ['only', => ['index']]);
Route::get('contacts','ContactsController@index');
```

After reinstalling laravel 4 now I am getting following error

```
404 Not Found

The requested URL /contacts was not found on this server.
_____________________________________________________________________
Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.15 with Suhosin-Patch Server at bb.dev Port 80
```

**Edit 3**

Here is what did now, I edit "/private/etc/apache2/users/.conf" and changed from "AllowOverride None" to "AllowOverride All" and then restarted my apache server. Now I am getting following error

```
403 Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /contacts on this server.
__________________________________________________________________________________
Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.15 with Suhosin-Patch Server at bb.dev Port 80
```

Why don't I have permission for this contacts controller? It is making me crazy now.

Here is my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Routes can be get, post, put.... Just change it to appropriate request. Plus read the documentation on routing.

Comment: @itachi the routes documentations on this [link](http://laravel.com/docs/routing) does not say that routes must be get, post, put etc. If you read comments on this [link](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/34) you will find out that the one which I am using is also possible.

Comment: By default, as far as i know, laravel supports get, post, put, head and delete request. If you open up the framework and see how routing is done, then you'l see that there are particular methods associated with each of these request. The problem arises if you are using a bundle. Are you using one? If yes, which one?

Comment: Resource controllers are covered in the documentation here: http://four.laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers. The resource() function is defined on line 216 of the Router class file.

Comment: I tested your code on my Laravel 4 - and it works. I'd try and reinstall Laravel4 and see if that fixes it. Might be another issue..

Comment: OK. Thanks. However, after reinstalling my laravel 4 following this [screencast](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ehY82-X9hBM), I am getting `Not Found The requested URL /contacts was not found on this server.` error after visiting my site `localhost/contacts`

Comment: Can you specify which function to use in your ContactsController, like: `Controller@method`

Comment: @adis If you need to know function inside my controller then I posted my entire controller above. I want to use index() function. Please my code above.

Comment: @TheShiftExchange Have you tried it? Could you please tell me what you get? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please see my latest updates. The errors are now changing but still not working :(

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried this on another server? A lot of things can go wrong with rewriting (I've lost hours fixing the .htaccess), so the problem may be Apache and not Laravel.

This works for me in `public/.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine on

     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And have you tried going to `index.php/contacts` instead of `/contacts`? If that works, the problem is Apache, not Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a namespace issue -- it should be calling the function on *Illuminate*\Routing\Router but your exception refers to *Laravel*\Routing\Route::resource().

Is it possible that your configuration file still has references to Laravel3 in it?

Comment: No I have never used laravel before. This is the first time I am using it and started with laravel 4. I haven't installed laravel 3 in the past

Comment: I reinstalled the entire laravel again by following one of the screencast on youtube. But this time it says `Not Found

The requested URL /contacts was not found on this server. `

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your routes to

```
Route::resource('/contacts', 'ContactsController');
```

In ContactsController.php change index to return instance of the model

```
public function index()
{
    return Contact::all();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same $#%& issue, and after hours of searching I found it is not a problem of the .httacess file. What I just did to fix this:

```
composer update --dev
```

I think that the `--dev` bit is the important thing. Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

ok i had the issue up to one minute ago! 
it  is because of ide-helper 
to solve you should comment the following code in routes.php

```
use Illuminate\Routing\Route;
```